# Vbs script to add space if it finds a string like abc11adv to abc11 adv

Tags: vbscript

Hi I am novice in vbs script. I have one text file every line has statements like

```
   minis1in use by bla bla  
   rit34in use by someone  
   atp34in use by someone2
```

I want a vbs script to convert this text file to

```
   minis1 in use by bla bla  
   rit34 in use by someone  
   atp34 in use by someone2
```

I found one vbs script but it replaces string at particular position in every line. But I want to search for a number only in first string in every line and number may be one digit or two digit or three digit after that number it should give space. Without replacing character with a space.

```
StrFileName = "C:\Users\Desktop\Scheduled\output.txt"

Const ForReading = 1    
Const ForWriting = 2
Dim objFSO
Dim objTF
Dim objRexex
Dim StrFileName
Dim strTxt

StrFileName = "C:\Users\Desktop\Scheduled\output.txt"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTF = objFSO.OpenTextFile(StrFileName, ForReading)
Set objregex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
strTxt = objTF.ReadAll
objTF.Close
With objregex
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .Pattern = "^(.{6})[^-](.*)$"
    strTxt = .Replace(strTxt, "$1" & " " & "$2")
End With

Set objTF = objFSO.OpenTextFile(StrFileName, ForWriting)
objTF.Write strTxt
objTF.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the pattern "^(\w+)(\d+)(\w+)" used non-globally will do what you want:

```
Option Explicit

Dim r : Set r = New RegExp
r.Global = False ' just the first
r.Pattern = "^(\w+)(\d+)(\w+)"
Dim s
For Each s In Split("minis1in use by+rit34adv use+atp34in use not34in use+not here1in use", "+")
    WScript.Echo s
    WScript.Echo r.Replace(s, "$1$2 $3")
    WScript.Echo
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 25228592.vbs
minis1in use by
minis1 in use by

rit34adv use
rit34 adv use

atp34in use not34in use
atp34 in use not34in use

not here1in use
not here1in use
```

Answer (score 0):

If *"every line has statements like"* what you've shown, and you're sure of that, make it easy on yourself:

```
strTxt = Replace(strTxt, "in use by ", " in use by ")
```

Comment: Even if you accept that assumption (in the face of "abc11adv to abc11 adv"), you'd have to deal with the "first word/just once" condition.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner I missed his title example. His question showed only "in use by" examples.